# export datatable to excel vb.net (new option)

Tags: vb.net, excel, gridview, datatable, export

I need export a DataTable to an Excel file using vb.net

I try with two different options, this work but generate conflicts with the labels in the front; somebody know other form to do this?

```
Dim GridTemp As New GridView()
GridTemp.AllowPaging = False
GridTemp.DataSource = baseIngresos
GridTemp.DataBind()
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=NO_Marcados" + Trim(Ipfechainicio.Text) + "_" + Trim(Ipfechafin.Text) + ".xls")
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

For i As Integer = 0 To GridTemp.Rows.Count - 1
         GridTemp.Rows(i).Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")
Next
GridTemp.RenderControl(hw)
Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
Response.Write(style)
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

And the other option that I use:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Dim pag As New Page()
Dim form As New HtmlForm()
Dim gridV As New GridView()
gridV.EnableViewState = False
gridV.DataSource = baseIngresos
gridV.DataBind()
pag.EnableEventValidation = False
pag.DesignerInitialize()
pag.Controls.Add(form)
form.Controls.Add(gridV)
pag.RenderControl(htw)
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=NO_Marcados" + Trim(Ipfechainicio.Text) + "_" + Trim(Ipfechafin.Text) + ".xls")
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default
Response.Write(sb.ToString())
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using `gridview`. I'm using a `datagridview` and used this code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


    'FOR HEADERS
    For i = 1 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, i) = DataGridView1.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
        'FOR ITEMS
        For j = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 1, i) = DataGridView1(i - 1, j - 1).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next


    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("You can find the file D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=samplelangtowalangya.mdb;"
    connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    sql = "update Users set Password = 'new password' where UserID = 'user1'"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand = connection.CreateCommand
        oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql
        oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Row(s) Updated !! ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

A excel file will be created in the path `"D:\vbexcel.xlsx"` and save it with the file name vbexcel.xlsx. Also, try reading about `Crystal Report`. It is widely used in generating reports and open it with excel.